# Django With Apache - Double Content In Response

Tags: django, apache, response, virtualhost

i use an apache to run my django instances.
my apache doubles the django output.

so in developement i get this:

```
my response text
```

but on apache "production", this:

```
my response text 
my response text
```

my vhost config look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>                                                                                              
    Alias /public /xxx/public                                          
    Redirect /robots.txt /public/robots.txt                                                              
    <Directory "/xxx">                                                        
        Order allow,deny                                                                             
        Allow from all                                                                               
    </Directory>                                                                                     
    ServerName www.xxx.de                                                                  
    ServerAlias *.xxx.de                                                                   
    SetHandler python-program                                                                            
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython                                                         
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings                                                               
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE '/tmp/python-eggs'                                                       
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython                                                     
    PythonDebug Off                                                                                  
    PythonPath "['', '/xxx'] + sys.pa
</VirtualHost>
```

i don't know whats wrong, do u know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether this is the issue, but you have PythonHandler written twice.
Also, [mod.wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is preferred to mod_python by many.

Comment: funny thing. that worked.seems to be the PythonHandler is evaluated twice.